# Brightness button does not work

Tags: brightness, button

When I press brightness contrast button to reduce and increase the brightness in Ubuntu it is neither showing any brightness bar nor having any effect on brightness.

However, when I manually change my brightness, it is working.

Comment: Unclear. Brightness issues are rather hardware-dependent. Please add your machine details , and explain what button you mean, and what you mean by "manually"

Answer (score 1):

The file you should fix is named "grub" at this address: 
Open Nautilus (Files), go to Computer

```
/etc/default/grub
```

to edit this you should have root access or just open terminal and run this

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Check this out:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

on the 11th line it says:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

so change it to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

and then run this command in terminal

```
sudo update-grub
```

then it should be fixed after restarting the system.

Sometimes it doesn't work like this, you may like to test the change like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` and restart

Comment: `/etc/default/grub` is the actual location of the file, not `Computer/etc/default/grub`.

Comment: The part about how you may not be able to access the file is pointless. You don't need to run `sudo gedit` then use the "Open" dialog, but just give the absolute path of the file in the command: `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`, as you wrote.

Comment: @wjandrea , you are right as a **pro** but lots of people using "Files" browser can't find it because "Files" opens `"/home"` as default. so they just need to click on the "computer" on the left side to find `"/etc"` at `"/"`

Comment: Oh, I see what you're getting at, but that's a confusing way to explain it, even for newcomers. It might be better to say "Open Nautilus (Files), go to **Computer** ...", but given the scope of your answer, you don't even need to mention Nautilus. I would say just leave it out entirely, especially since not everyone uses Nautilus; in fact, if I open **Computer** in Nemo, it takes me to `computer:///`, which has a list of disks, not the FS root.

Comment: @wjandrea , tnx dude, I used your advice and I hope it had got better